# Agrupar y Sumar

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Tengo la siguiente consulta**

```
SELECT  T0.TxInvPRLote ,T0.TxInvPRProducto ,T0.TxInvPRPeso AS PesoInventarioPR, T1.peso AS PesoDeshuese ,T2.CodBarras_Planta
FROM  [dbo].[tblinv_txinventarioPR] T0 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbldeshuese] T1 ON T0.TxInvPRLote = T1.codlote
INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tblarticulos] T2 ON  T0.TxInvPRProducto = T2.codigo
WHERE TxInvPRLote ='17732'
```

**que me arroja el siguiente resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**hay varios productos como el PT-105 con un peso necesito agrupar este producto y sumar su peso no solo esta el PT-105 si no muchos mas**

Comment: ¿Has buscado como usar `SUM()` y `GROUP BY`?

Comment: si se utilizarlos pero no pensé que fuera así, lo estaba haciendo de otra forma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es agrupar ese campo solo tienes que agrupar por el producto y luego sumar el peso, de esa manera obtendras lo que necesitas,

ejemplo tu codigo deberia quedar asi mas o menos, espero que te funcione,

```
    SELECT T0.TxInvPRProducto, sum(PesoInventarioPR)
    FROM  [dbo].[tblinv_txinventarioPR] T0 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbldeshuese] T1 ON T0.TxInvPRLote = T1.codlote
    INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tblarticulos] T2 ON  T0.TxInvPRProducto = T2.codigo
    WHERE TxInvPRLote ='17732'
GROUP BY  T0.TxInvPRProducto
```

Comment: En lugar de usar WHERE deberías utilizar HAVING puesto que, con WHERE podemos hacer una condición para registros individuales y con HAVING una condición sobre un grupo de registros.

Comment: No utilizo el having porque el no solamente querrar obtener los productos que tengan mas de 2 registros por eso no lo utilizo, por fines de optimizacion si no lo esta especificando que son solo los que tienen mas registros entiendo que no es necesario